# LateInitializationError: Field has not been initialized.' .then() command not running after running firebase query in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to retrieve a Firestore Snapshot and my code doesn't seem to be working. I made sure `fireUser.uid` was working, and it printed the right ID but strangely my `.then()` code isn't running at all I put `print('then')` in it and isn't appearing on my console

this is where the error is occurring:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait([
      DatabaseService.getUserDataFromFirestore(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!),
      GeoService.getPosition(),
      ]),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Frame();
        }
        else return Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Center(
            child: spinKit,
          ),
        );
      }
    );
```

Future with error:

```
static Future<Userdata> getUserDataFromFirestore (User fireUser) async {
    await usersRef.doc(fireUser.uid).get().then((val) {
      print('then');
      userdata = Userdata.fromDoc(val);
    });
    return userdata;
  }
```

error message:

```
LateInitializationError: Field 'userdata' has not been initialized.
```

Comment: Are you certain the error comes from the `return userdata` line?

Comment: no the error comes from later in my code when I try to use 'userdata', sorry I wasn't very clear about that

Comment: `late` should be used *only* if you can logically guarantee that you initialize `userdata` before it's used.  If you can't make that guarantee, then make it nullable and check for a `null` value wherever you use it.

Comment: it should always be initialized this code has worked for me before but all of the sudden when I opened flutter today it stopped working. I think the issue is coming from where ".then()" is because that code doesn't even run at all

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `.then` usage (other than it being bad style to mix `.then` with `await`).  However, you are relying on an asynchronous operation to initialize `userdata`, which is a bad idea for `late` variables since that provides more opportunities to access it before it's initialized.  You aren't seeing your callback fire because you access `userdata` and trigger the `LateInitializationError` *before* the callback executes.

Comment: I tried what you said and now the future builder just loads forever after trying a few different codes I think the issue is that it is not retrieving the DocumentSnapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a different problem then I thought. Firestore must have been updated because the rules of my Firestore database kept me locked out so I updated the rules and now my code works fine. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: FYI, the `LateInitializationError` likely is indicative of a separate problem that was exposed by your `Future` not completing.  That is, if you don't fix it, it might happen again if that `Future` ever happens to take longer to complete than usual.